# Dojo1.8 - decode the network error and display it correctly

Tags: dojo

Hi I have a network error on purpose of the wrong file and I need to decode it. 
How do I do that? When I output the error into dialog, it cannot be defined.

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/request", "dojo/dom",
"dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"])
function(parser, Button, request, dom, Dialog)
{
var myDialog = new Dialog({
    title: "Response",
    style: "width: 300px"
    });

var button1 = new Button({
    label: "Click Me!",
onClick:function()
{request("brownfox.txt").then(
        function(text){
            dom.byId("textnote").innerHTML=text;
        },

        function(error)
            myDialog.set("content", error);
            myDialog.show();
        }
});
```

The output would be "

### 404 Not Found

Not Found

The requested URL /brownfox.txt was not found on this server.

"

OR from network error = "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mytestphp.net/brownfox.txt"

Please advise. Thanks

regards
Clement

Comment: if "function(msg, url, linenumber){alert('Error Message:'+msg)} return true", it works. But if "myDialog.set("content", 'Error message'+msg)" is used, it does not work. Any idea  how it can be fixed.